# How to copy/export symbols for multiple layers to another project at once

Tags: qgis

I got a qgis project with different layers and each layer has a different svg-symbol. Now I need the same symbols for another qgis project with slightly different layers. Is there an option to copy all the symbols at once and paste it to the other project layers? I just know the method to create styling files for all the layers seperated which is time consuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to set relative paths in the project and replace the data with new ones automatically (file names must be the same for this).
[image]

Example. Original folder:

C:\folder_**1**\project_file.qgz `(original project file)`

C:\folder_**1**\vector_data_1.gpkg

New folder:

C:\folder_**2**\project_file.qgz `(original project file)`

C:\folder_**2**\vector_data_1.gpkg `(other data file with the same name)`

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail? Whats next after setting relative path names? How to replace the data with new ones automatically?

Comment: @Barrylim_work See update.

Answer (score 0):

You could write two functions with pyqgis.

1. Iterate over all Layers: For each layer save Style as `YOUR/DESIRED/FOLDER/layername.qml`
2. Iterate over all Layers: For each layer load Style from `YOUR/DESIRED/FOLDER/layername.qml`

You need to write it just once. Then you can use it whenever you want. Then its just time consuming for the first time!